# How to find the duplicate value in a column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In the query current I am only trying to count the records having duplicate but how should I check and remove the duplicates and show only single values

```
SELECT email, COUNT(email) 
FROM users
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(email) > 1
```

So currently below is the values present in the table

```
ID   NAME   EMAIL
----------------------------
1    John   asd@asd@msp@bw
2    Sam    asd@com@wap
3    Tom    asd@wap@mop@asd
4    Bob    asd@sap@bad@asd
5    Tom    asd@man@asd@can
```

Requirement - in `email` column `asd@asd` is there how should I remove the first `asd` or the last `asd` and keep only single asd in the response?

And if there is only 1 `asd`, then we can ignore it.

Output needed

```
ID   NAME   EMAIL
------------------------
1    John   asd@msp@bw
2    Sam    asd@com@wap
3    Tom    asd@wap@mop
4    Bob    asd@sap@bad
5    Tom    asd@man@can
```

Comment: Why on row 1 & 2 do you remove the 2nd "asd" but on row 3 remove the first "asd"

Comment: As an example I was showing I wanted to remove asd which are repeated

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm checking your task, and I think you can use STP to make the script work with your string and fix it the way you want it, so here's an example, it's not the best algorithm, but it's an approach that gets the result, as the field is a email you must have a separator between the emails, then replace what is in the variable SET @character = '@' change @ for your separator char.

```
DECLARE @character as char(1)
DECLARE @text as nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @nchar as int
DECLARE @i as int
DECLARE @resulttext as nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @index as int
DECLARE @newtext as nvarchar(50)

Declare @forId as int
Declare @forEmail as nvarchar(50)


SET @character = '@'

DECLARE @table1 TABLE
(
    id int, 
    username varchar(50), 
    email varchar(50)
)


INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES 
(1,'John', 'asd@asd@msp@bw'), 
(2,'Sam', 'asd@com@wap'), 
(3,'Tom', 'asd@wap@mop@asd'), 
(4,'Bob', 'asd@sap@bad@asd'), 
(5,'Tom', 'asd@man@asd@can')


SELECT * FROM @table1

--Cursor
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    
    SELECT id,email FROM @table1;

    OPEN db_cursor  
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @forId, @forEmail

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  

        SET @text = @forEmail
        SET @resulttext = ''

        while LEN(@text) > 0
        begin
            --get the index of the position of the character
            SET @index = CHARINDEX(@character,@text)

            if @index = 0
                begin
                    SET @newtext = @text
                    SET @text = ''
                    --finish with the last text
                    SET @resulttext = @resulttext + @newtext
                end
            else
                begin   
                    --get the substring
                    SET @newtext = SUBSTRING(@text,1,@index)

                    --Remove string with @
                    SET @text = REPLACE(@text, @newtext, '')
                    --Remove string without @
                    if CHARINDEX(@character,@newtext) > 0
                        SET @text = REPLACE(@text, Left(@newtext,len(@newtext)-1), '') 
                    --mount the result
                    SET @resulttext = @resulttext + @newtext 

                end
        end
        
        --if the end of result have @ remove it.
        if CHARINDEX(@character,Right(@resulttext,1)) > 0 
            SET @resulttext = LEFT(@resulttext,len(@resulttext)-1)

        --update the value in table by id
        UPDATE @table1 SET email = @resulttext WHERE id = @forId

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO  @forId, @forEmail 
    END 

    CLOSE db_cursor  
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor 

SELECT * FROM @table1
```

The original result

```
id  username    email
1   John        asd@asd@msp@bw
2   Sam         asd@com@wap
3   Tom         asd@wap@mop@asd
4   Bob         asd@sap@bad@asd
5   Tom         asd@man@asd@can
```

After script

```
id  username    email
1   John        asd@msp@bw
2   Sam         asd@com@wap
3   Tom         asd@wap@mop
4   Bob         asd@sap@bad
5   Tom         asd@man@can
```

Best Regards